# How do I make asp menu extend to the end of the page when scrolling?

Tags: asp.net, css, html, menu, scroll

I have a horizontal asp menu in a div. The div is set set to width:100% which fills the width of the page, however when the page can be horizontally scrolled the div doesn't extend to the end of the page. I have tried setting min-width%:100%; in the CSS of the div, however this doesn't make a difference. Can anyone help me to solve this problem by telling me how to make the div fill out the width of the page when the page can be horizontal scrolled. I am using CSS 2.1 and ASP.NET 2.0

The code for the div is:

```
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu"     EnableViewState="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <staticmenuitemstyle  ItemSpacing="30"/>
                           <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="DarkGray" BorderColor="Black"     BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1"></StaticHoverStyle>  
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Home.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Report.aspx" Text="Report an   Operational Risk"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/View.aspx" Text="View Reported Operational Risks"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/UpdateClose.aspx" Text="Update/Close a    Case"/>                      
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
```

The CSS for the div and menu  is:

```
.hideSkiplink
{
background-color:#FF9900;
width:100%;
float:left;
}

.menu
{
padding: 4px 0px 4px 12px;
}

.menu ul
{
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: auto;
}

.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
background-color: #FF9900;
color: #000000;
font-weight: bold;
font-size:14px;
display: block;
line-height: 1.35em;
padding: 4px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu ul li a:hover
{
background-color: #bfcbd6;
color: #465c71;
text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul li a:active
{
background-color: #465c71;
color: #cfdbe6;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding "float:left" to the div?

Comment: Yeah I just tried that now and there was no difference. What was that supposed to do?

Comment: Well with this basic fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ffMLs/, I can get it to span 2000px just by setting float:left. Is there some other option in your HTML layout that is limiting the size of the div?

Comment: @MightyLampshade I don't think so. I have posted all the code that I believe affects the menu in the original post

Comment: Ah, in the CSS class "clear" are you specifying clear:both? That will stop the `float:left` property working.

Comment: @MightyLampshade Yeah I did have clear:both in the css class 'Clear' so I took it out but it still doesn't work. Even if i do floaat:right it has no efect. It seems as if float isn't working, im using CSS 2.1 ann asp.net 2.0

Comment: Try wrapping it like this. I think I messed up that fiddle before, sorry :(

http://jsfiddle.net/ffMLs/2/

Comment: @MightyLampshade Okay I will try this on Tuesday, I would like you to know that I do not have a fixed width, the width always changes so I will not enter a fixed width like you did. Im not sure if it will still work

Comment: @MightyLampshade I still couldn't get this to work. I think this is because I do not have a fixed width

Comment: Hmm a fixed width should not matter when you are using `float:left` with a width of 100%. Is your page dynamically increasing it's size horizontally? Are you adding objects during runtime that extends the page? Also, have you checked whether your `html` and `body` CSS have a width of 100%? You could also try specifying `float:left` on the `html` or `body` elements.

Comment: Yes the page is creating its size based on a gridview which dynamically changes. The body is 100% but html is not defined in the CSS. Thanks for the help you have given so far, it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I put the gridview in a scrollable div so that the page has a fixed width.